# why I have to transfer same php script in binary now?

Tags: php, netbeans

I had developed a script, earlier I use to transfer it directly without any transfer mode selection, recently i developed and improved it, now I have to transfer it via binary mode, I am using same ftp client (FileZilla), but i have changed my ide from phpDesigner to netbeans.

Can anybody Please explain me why is this happening, and a solution to it, as it is causing problems to me because i cant distribute it freely without any documentation.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your new IDE using a character encoding that looks like binary to Filezila.

eg, if you were using ascii and are now using utf16, then every other byte in the file is likely to be a zero, which filezilla will see as a binary file.

Comment: You could check the "save as" dialog, or some IDE's list the encoding in the status bar somewhere. Failing that, search the help for character encoding and see what encodings are supported and how you tell it which one you want to use. You can also just look at the raw bytes in your file and see if it contains what you are expecting it to.

Comment: Thank You. Any software that automatically changes character encodings and which encoding should i use.

Comment: I expect you are working in English, with very little expectation to need anything more exotic than this. If that is the case, use something like ISO-8859-1 which will look like text to anything. If you want to future proof yourself a bit, try and use utf8. I guess it would be sensible to use whatever encoding your website is using.